# Calling content before jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code where I want to load content and then trigger a plugin. Can some one please assist me as its not working and I'm not proficient enough to debug myself!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#scoop-container ul').load('/test.html');

$("#scoop-container ul").carouFredSel({
    direction: "up",
    height: "variable",
    height: 1000,
    items: {
        start: "random"
    },
    scroll: 1
});
});
```

Comment: Please define "its not working."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the code in the callback function (second argument):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#scoop-container ul').load('/test.html', function() {
    $("#scoop-container ul").carouFredSel({ direction: "up", height: "variable", height: 1000, items: { start: "random" }, scroll: 1 }); });
  });
});
```

The callback function is executed when the request completes.

Comment: Please change the `$("#scoop-container ul")` inside the callback function to `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, load it in the callback:

```
$('#scoop-container ul').load('/test.html', function(){
    //do the carouFredSel stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the function call in the callback of the `.load()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scoop-container ul').load('/test.html',null,function(){
        $("#scoop-container ul").carouFredSel({
             direction: "up",
             height: "variable",
             height: 1000,
             items: {
                start: "random"
             },
             scroll: 1
        });
    });
});
```

See here: http://api.jquery.com/load/. Most jQuery functions are like this - they have a parameter called `callback` where you can write an entire function to be executed when the previous one is complete. You can also nest them - quite convenient, but it can look pretty messy with all those indents.

Answer (score 0):

```
('/test.html');
```

I suspect the path is the problem. Adding the slash to the front part will make your application search for the file in the root of your site. Check if the path is correct. I checked the function call which should be fine.